# How the shots belonging to the same job are scheduled to run on IBM quantum devices?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

How the shots belonging to the same job are scheduled to run on IBM quantum devices? Suppose my job has 1000 shots. Will all shots be executed in series, or is it possible they will be interleaved with shots corresponding to jobs submitted by other users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, jobs submitted by users are added to a queue, and the quantum computer processes jobs in the order they are received. If there is high demand for the quantum device, you may experience some wait time in the queue. The execution of your shots may not happen immediately, and there might be other users' jobs interleaved with yours.

But once your job is submitted, it runs the circuit for the entire duration of the number of shots you have given.

For Example:

Suppose you have sent a VQE model to train, and once you run the circuit for one time for `num_shots=1000` you receive one value which is then sent to the classical cost function to evaluate which then changes the Rotation gate parameters.

In this case, the first iteration of the quantum circuit will run as a whole, no matter how many shots you have defined (the max being 8192). Then once it runs, it'll give a number that will be sent to the cost function, which then evaluates and the optimizer changes the rotation gates parameters. Then, the next iteration of the quantum circuit will be queued behind the other circuits (if any).

This can also be seen if you click on the [Jobs section](https://quantum.ibm.com/jobs) of the IBMQ page, and select any of the previous jobs you have run.

You can see the number of shots there:

[image]